# Auto restart a macro to run once per day

Tags: excel, vba

I need to send reminders 7 days before a certain deadline.

With help I managed to create this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object
    Dim strto, strcc, strbcc, strsub, strbody As String
        
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
    For i = 2 To Range("e65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 9) <> "Y" Then
            If Cells(i, 5) - 7 < Date Then
                    
                strto = Cells(i, 7).Value 'email address
                strsub = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " compleanno il " & Cells(i, 5).Value 'email subject
                strbody = "Il compleanno di " & Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " sarà il " & Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine 'email body
                    
                With OutMail
                    .To = strto
                    .Subject = strsub
                    .Body = strbody
                    .Send 
                End With
                    
                Cells(i, 8) = "Mail Sent " & Now()
                Cells(i, 9) = "Y"
                    
            End If
        End If
    Next
        
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have to start it manually every day because even if the deadline is updated the macro doesn't restart by itself.

I tried replacing Sub Workbook_Activate() with Sub Workbook_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range).

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't restart by itself"*? It starts always when you activate the workbook (that means before there needs to be another workbook activated). Note that *"still doesn't work"* is a very useless error description. Also please describe how you handle this file? Do you open it once and leave it open/running for a year or do you open/close it every day? What are you doing?

Comment: Just because you can do something in Excel doesn't mean you should.  Perhaps using Outlook would be a more stable option.  Here is one of many examples I found searching: https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-send-recurring-email-periodically-outlook-vba/

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for your answer and sorry for my inexperience.
 
I didn't realize that actually if I open the workbook, leave it open, then work on another file and then go back to the first one the macro starts again.

I would need, however, for the macro to start automatically whenever any cell in that workbook changes, e.g. if the deadline coutdown is reduced.

Thanks again

Comment: @sous2817 I already knew this method and tried several times without success. Now I honestly don't remember what problem I had but it was related to the company policy.

Comment: @UmbertoRoselli `Worksheet_Change` runs whenever a constant cell value changes in the worksheet (not a formula) `Worksheet_Calculate` runs whenever anything in the worksheet is recalculated. `Workbook_SheetChange` runs whenever a constant cell value changes in any worksheet (not a formula).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks again, I tried with "calculate" but it sends me a bunch of emails. If I want to run it only once a day instead, how could I do that?

Comment: @UmbertoRoselli I would use `Application.OnTime` and save the last run time on the sheet.